# How to pass Class variable of generic type in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have a function that expects class

```
someMethod(Class<T> c){}
```

which for a normal class it's easy, you can just do

```
someMethod(MyObject.class)
```

But for some reason this wont work

```
 someMethod(MyObject<User>.class)
```

wont compile. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing.  `MyObject<User>.class` would be exactly the same thing as `MyObject.class`.  There is no separate `Class` object for different subtypes; `Class` is an API that *only* represents a "raw" type, not generic.  It's just not what `Class` is for.

If you need one to make generics work, just cast it: e.g. `(Class<MyObject<User>>) MyObject.class`.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, it's your object which decided what would be the type of the object as you already declared that when object was created. There is not point in doing `object<Type>.class` as it's already determined during object creation. You can always typecast if required.